# Redux createAsyncThunk naming convention

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

one quick question,
is it ok to use the same label for my asyncthunk setup ?
in my SS it shown as `fetchFOrmData` - `users/fetchFormData`
since in the doc it always shown as different label

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion-based question.

First, we should know the recommended naming convention for the redux action type. See [Write Action Types as domain/eventName](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#write-action-types-as-domaineventname)

> we suggest using the **"domain/action"** convention for readability.

Personally, I prefer keeping the thunk name the same as the `action` part of `domain/action`.

E.g.

`users.slice.ts`:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchAllUsers = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchAllUsers', () => []);
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchUserById', () => ({}));
```

`locations.slice.ts`:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchAllLocations = createAsyncThunk('locations/fetchAllLocations', () => []);
export const fetchLocationById = createAsyncThunk('locations/fetchLocationById', () => ({}));
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { fetchLocationById, fetchAllLocations } from './location.slice';
import { fetchUserById, fetchAllUsers } from './user.slice';

function main() {
  fetchUserById();
  fetchAllUsers();

  fetchLocationById();
  fetchAllLocations();
}
```

There are several advantages:

1. If we use `fetchAll`, we have to use namespace import (`import * as usersSlice from './users.slice.ts'`) or import alias. Otherwise, the `fetchAll` of the user slice and location slice will be in conflict.

```
import * as userSlice from './user.slice';
import * as locationSlice from './location.slice';

function main() {
  userSlice.fetchAll();
  userSlice.fetchById();

  locationSlice.fetchAll();
  locationSlice.fetchById();
}
```

2. When we search globally in the editor or IDE, `fetchAllUsers` will be more accurate and have fewer search results than `fetchAll`.
3. We don't need to map between the action type(`users/fetchAllUsers`) and the thunk name(`fetchAllUsers`) when reading the code and debug.

I have seen many projects keep the thunk name the same as the action type name.

[grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/v9.1.3/public/app/features/plugins/admin/state/actions.ts) uses this naming convension.